# How to use 3rd party modules in expo/react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a project using

```
expo init myApp
```

Then installed a 3rd party react native module using

```
expo install my-module
```

Then in my App.js

```
import myClass from 'my-module';
```

Then I run

```
expo prebuild
expo start
```

Then I scan the barcode using the camera app on my iPhone and it opens in Expo Go

Then I see my splash screen and it comes up with these errors

```
NativeModule.myClass is null
```

(breaking on the import line, complaining about not being linked, tried linking and makes no difference, and complaining about rebuilding the app, but how do I rebuild?)

```
"main" has not been registered.
```

(can happen if metro running from wrong folder, module failed to load or 'AppRegistry.registerComponent' wasn't called)

I have tried multiple modules with no success. I feel like it has to do with building the app but I'm not sure what I am missing.

Or am I misunderstanding that I should be able to build and test locally without making an ipa/apk.

Can I only test a 3rd party module by using a device simulator?

Comment: This is on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square is a rectangle but a rectangle is not a square. Likewise, react native is expo but expo is not react native.

1. Make sure that when you are looking for packages that you search for `expo [feature required]` instead of `react [feature required]`. It is likely the case that what you are looking for is already in expo and you don't need to do a weird install.
2. Importing follows this pattern: `import * as MyClass from 'my-module';`
3. Use `PowerShell`. Part of the scripting for expo is done in PowerShell so it helps to just run everything from there for sanity.
4. The `Expo Go` App is only really good for testing UI changes and interactivity. It is not suited for testing device specific features like reading from sensors. Use an emulator or build it to run on your device for optimal testing. Testing on web locally may work in some circumstances.